# Generate keycloak user setting page URL

Tags: jakarta-ee, wildfly, keycloak

I know the user setting page is:

https://DOMAIN:PORT/auth/realms/REALM/account/?referrer=APPLICATION

Is there anyway to generate this URL on a servlet without hard-coding server DOMAIN and the other parameters (Getting these parameters from keycloak.json or from application server by any provided API)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by getting the Keycloak AdapterDeploymentContext from the ServletContext:

```
AdapterDeploymentContext deploymentContext = (AdapterDeploymentContext) getServletContext().getAttribute(AdapterDeploymentContext.class.getName());
KeycloakDeployment deployment = deploymentContext.resolveDeployment(null);
```

The deployment can then be queried for getAuthServerBaseUrl() & getRealm(). I got this to work in TomEE 1.7.1 (aka Tomcat 7 with the 1.1.0-Final of Keycloak) I'm sure it will work in Java-EE Wildfly too.

For this you need to maven-provide these artifacts:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-adapter-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```